# How to change bitmap and label of an Button component [Flash CS5, ActionScript-s]

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3, flash-cs5

I have created one button component using one Bitmap and one Label in it.
Thing is that when user Clicks on on the button I want to changes button's Icon/Image and Label Text.

I want to do this using FlashCS5 and ActionScript-3.

I have tried following but it gives me runtime Error

```
[Bindable]
[Embed(source="/Images/test.png")]
var testIcon:Class; 

testButton.setStyle("icon", testIcon);
```

Is there any other way of doing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you want to archive i think you should follow following steps
1. Create one movie clip using new symbol 
2. Create Two new Button Symbol using 2 different images and label 
3. insert these button into the key frames  for the created movie clip

you can use this movieClip to create new buttons that can have 2 states 
just use gotoAndStop to display the proper button.

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate `testIcon` first. Try doing this:

```
[Embed(source="/Images/test.png")]
var testIcon:Class;

var btnGraphics:Bitmap = new testIcon();
testButton.setStyle("icon", btnGraphics);
```

Comment: +1 also he doesn't need the `[Bindable]`. It doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @Jacob Eggers, Good point. I updated my answer to reflect the entire code needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but getting run-time error:   ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property style not found on flash.display.SimpleButton and there is no default value.
 at ActionScript::TestPage/TestBtnClicked()

Comment: You need to post some more of your code for me to help you with that. At the very least the function `TestBtnClicked`

Comment: Function TestBtnClicked Does not contain any more code than this it just changes button image to test.png

Comment: When it says Property style not found, it's usually the case that you're trying to do something like `mySimpleButton.style = myStyle` but the function `public function set style(style:Object)` is not defined in the class SimpleButton.

Comment: Thanks Its working now, but how can I align my image above Text in the button. One more thing, is there any way in Flash CS5 that i can directly add image to an button from .fla/movie clip only other than setting it through ActionScript?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by directly add an image to a button. You can  import the image into flash and add it to a MovieClip, then export that MovieClip to ActionScript with an identifier of your choice. In your code, instead of using all that Embed code, just call `getDefinitionByName` to start using your MovieClip. Was that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer for a followup that ppp asked:

1. There is a property `labelPlacement="right|left|bottom|top"` property. Default is `right` if you set it to bottom, the icon will show above the text.
2. You can create a button skin in flash and import them into flex. My experience with flex 3 skins imported from Flash is that it takes a bit of work and back and forth to get it working perfectly. Flash Catalyst for Flex 4 has greatly improved that workflow.